# Value initialization of POD struct is a constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, default-constructor, value-initialization

Consider the struct:

```
struct mystruct { };
```

Is it true that this is always valid:

```
constexpr mystruct mystructInstance = mystruct();
```

i.e. that value initialization of POD is a `constexpr`?  Similarly how about if the struct is defined to be:

```
struct mystruct { ~mystruct(); };
```

Finally, what about this:

```
struct mystruct { mystruct(); ~mystruct(); };
```

I haven't declared the ctr as constexpr, however are there any implicit deduction rules which guaratee this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [requirements for `constexpr` variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) are:

> A constexpr variable must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - its type must be a LiteralType.
> - it must be immediately constructed or assigned a value.
> - the constructor parameters or the value to be assigned must contain only literal values, constexpr variables and functions.
> - the constructor used to construct the object (either implicit or explicit) must satisfy the requirements of constexpr constructor. In the case of explicit constructor, it must have constexpr specified.

---

Given your 3 structs:

```
struct mystruct_1 { };
struct mystruct_2 { ~mystruct_2(); };
struct mystruct_3 { mystruct_3(); ~mystruct_3(); };
```

---

`mystruct_1` is a [`LiteralType`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType). So the following is valid and compiles:

```
constexpr mystruct_1 mystructInstance_1 = mystruct_1();
```

---

`mystruct_2` is **not** a `LiteralType` since it has a non-trivial destructor.
Therefore the following is invalid and fails to compile:

```
constexpr mystruct_2 mystructInstance_2 = mystruct_2();
```

---

The same applies for `mystruct_3`, additionally it is not an [aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special) and does not provide a `constexpr` constructor.
So the following is also invalid and fails to compile:

```
constexpr mystruct_3 mystructInstance_3 = mystruct_3();
```

---

You can also have a look at the descriptive error messages in this [online demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/kXgjKP4gOA15ch2V).

Comment: Great, thanks for that.  I'm basically trying to assure that MSVC is incorrect in behaviour before I submit a bug.  I was pleased to see constexpr was finally implemented in VS 2015, but it still doesn't work properly.  Case 1 above fails in VS, even with 2015 [sigh]. +1 for the link as well.  That's an awesome tool.  Useful in conjunction with http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/.

Comment: The page for LiteralType have been moved to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType